# Excel VBA code for Pivot tables to clear filters then filter for selected range

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have multiple pivots in a workbook but one of the worksheets is called "YTD Payment Trend" and the Pivot table name is "Pivottable2". I am trying to Clear the filter named "TotalAccountBalance" and then filter for a range between -5.00 thru +5.00 only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtruy.png)

Below is what I have so far and I am attaching the image of the specific filter items but I need to be able to select a range since it can change:

```
Sub TESTMACRO()

    Dim PT As PivotTable
    Dim TAB1 As PivotField
    
    Set PT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YTD Payment Trend").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set TAB1 = PT.PivotFields("TotalAccountBalance")
    
    '//Reset Pivot Field Filter
    TAB1.ClearAllFilters
    
    '//Enable Multiple Items Selection
    TAB1.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
      
    Set TAB1 = Nothing
    Set PT = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe : `for each pit in TAB1.pivotitems: 
if pit >= -5 and pit <=5 then pit.visible = true else pit.visible = false: 
next` . But it will take a very long time to run if there are so many items in TAB1. *Not tested on my side*

Comment: If trying that out - be aware you must have at least one item visible.